# How to import 3D model to the object on scene in code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d-modelling

I have a kind of the fbx models, which were copied to folder unity's project by a user in runtime. I have to show those models on a new scene by simply replacing the models on one object.
At the entrance, I have paths to models and an empty object on the scene. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please check the help section for guidance on how to improve your question, such as showing what you have attempted so far. Kind regards DaggeJ

Comment: Your model contains a so-called Mesh. Have your main script use e.g. `[SerializeField] GameObject otherObject = null;`, then add it in inspector, then you can replace the object as whole, or use GetComponent to specifically replace only some parts, like the MeshFilter. Watching some Unity tutorials around these topics should help. Also check out Prefabs to see if they are useful in your case.